# Problem with fstab after 23.04 upgrade - mounts now read only

Tags: mount, fstab, 23.04

I ran an older Ubuntu version that approached EOL, so I upgraded to 23.04 yesterday.
After the upgrade, none of my network mounts worked any more.

Here's the old line from fstab:

```
//192.168.1.2/FolderA  /home/username/Desktop/FolderA cifs defaults,username=USER,password=123,vers=1.0
```

Now when I change the vers=1.0 to 2.0, the directory mounts fine, but read-only.

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

In v23.04 using the following entries at the end of the fstab line (after the password= entry) allows full read/write access to the mounts (to my NAS) on my system
`,rw,uid=1000,gid=500`

Your line would then read as follows:

```
//192.168.1.2/FolderA /home/username/Desktop/FolderA cifs username=USER,password=123,rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

Test it out using `sudo mount -a -v` (the verbose option) to make sure its doesn't break anything.

Comment: This does not work at all, I'm afraid. Mount -a -v returns: 
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.2.99,unc=\\192.168.2.99\FolderA,uid=1000,gid=500,user=USER,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

Comment: does [this](https://www.abrandao.com/2022/01/fix-mount-error95-operation-not-supported-smb/) help with the mount error message? In particular installing cifs-utils

Answer (score 0):

```
//192.168.1.2/FolderA  /home/username/Desktop/FolderA cifs defaults,username=USER,password=123,vers=2.0
```

had to become

```
//192.168.1.2/FolderA  /home/username/Desktop/FolderA cifs defaults,username=USER,password=123,uid=USER,vers=2.0
```

...and now it's working again.